# Angular 2 dynamic html

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components, angular2-compiler

I have created a table in angular 2 view and i want to bind html or angular component dynamically.

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let hHeader of hHeaders;let x=index">
        <td class="hour"><span>{{hHeader}}</span></td>
        <td *ngFor="let vHeader of vHeaders;let y=index" class="hour " [contextMenu]="basicMenu " [contextMenuSubject]="{t:hHeader,d:vHeader,x:x,y:y} ">
          <div #values [class.cell]="cell" id="cell-{{x}}-{{y}}" style="width:100%; height: 100%"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I can identify each cell in component

```
for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
      if (cells[i].nativeElement.id == 'cell-' + event.x + '-' + event.y) {
        // cells[i].nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#5789D8';
        cells[i].nativeElement.innerHTML = '<div class="drag" dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true">Drag me</div>'
        console.log(cells[i]);
      }
    }
```

but i can't bind html or Component like this.

```
<div class="drag" dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true">Drag me</div>
```

Comment: what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: i want to add html or angular 2 component to <td>

Comment: Do not program like this. The DOM is a not a big string that you construct and stick in somewhere. Even if you do do that, no Angular logic within your big innerHTML string will be interpreted. Write HTML in your template.

Comment: @torazaburo i want to bind html to <td>. what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to bind html to your td like it sounds, then you can just use the innerHTML attribute

```
<td ...[innerHTML]="whateverValue"...>
```

Comment: i think `nativeElement.innerHTML = '<div class="drag" dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true">Drag me</div>'` this one is not compile through compilor. it takes as string. i used some npm packages. they are not working

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using pipes for this. https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis

I found this one in a forum https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/inserting-html-via-angular-2-use-of-domsanitizationservice-bypasssecuritytrusthtml/62562/2

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

}

    public transform(value: string, type: string = 'html'): SafeHtml |  SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified:     ${type}`);
        }
    }

}
```

To implement just use `<component-container [innerHtml]='this.safteyPipe.transform(TemplateComponentString)'></component-container>`